# How can I find out if a user is trying to print

Tags: jquery, css, http-headers

I have a webform that has a `print.css.`

The textboxes/textareas in my form are often overflowed with text.
So when i go to print the form, it cuts off the content in the textboxes.

I need a way to replace all the inputs with divs when the user tries to print the form.
The Javascript should be fine to implement this.

But how do I know when a user is trying to print, is there a way I can find out?

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to capture the event of printing. Instead, use CSS-media based stylesheets, like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="web.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

However, some browsers now support the `window.onbeforeprint` and `window.onafterprint`, but that is only Firefox >=6.0 and IE

I've found [this](http://tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/) resource useful for detecting print requests cross browser

Comment: yes, i am using a print.css also, but CSS cannot stop my text in textboxes from getting cut off.